# How to create service that will store currently active menu?

Tags: angularjs

By clicking the link i change view, this re-instantiating my controller. This is why the activeMenu is empty. If icreate a service and store the currently active menu in there, it won't be empty.How can i create service to do that? This is my first time that i need to create service?This is my plnkr... http://plnkr.co/edit/gJko3umteXXEye7o9StR?p=preview
Problem is when user click on menu from layout then this re-instantiating my controller

Layout:

```
  <li class="dropdown">

<ul class="submenu">
<li><a href="../Account/#/PersonalInfo" ng-click="SetActiveMenuForPersonalInfo();">@Translate("MY_ACCOUNT")</a></li>
<li ng-click="GetLoader();"><a href="#">@Translate("SETTINGS")</a></li>
<li ng-click="GetLoader();"><a href="../Account/#/Tickets">@Translate("TICKET_HISTORY")</a></li>
<li ng-click="GetLoader();"><a href="../Account/#/Transactions">@Translate("TRANSACTIONS")</a></li>
<li ng-click="GetLoader();"><a href="#">@Translate("BONUS_ACCOUNT")</a></li>
<li><a href="#">@Translate("ODDS_REPRENSETATION")</a></li>
<li><a href="#">@Translate("HELP")</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">@Translate("LOGOUT")</a></li>
  </ul> </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
app.service('navigation', function () {
  this.activeLink = '';
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, navigation) {  
  $scope.activeMenu = 'Home';
  $scope.activeLink = navigation.activeLink;

  $scope.changeActiveLink = function(link) {
    $scope.activeLink = link;
    this.activeLink = link;
  }
});
```

**The service is a singleton**, it's intatiaded once per you application load, so it will keep the assigned value between diffent states of your app.

You can make it a bit smarter if you won't store a simple string value but an object - this way we'll be able to keep the reference to the service's value rather than the value itself and we won't need to set both `$scope.activeLink = link;` and `this.activeLink = link;` explicitly:

```
app.service('navigation', function () {
  this.active = {
    link: '',
    menu: 'Home'
  };
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, navigation) {
  $scope.activenav = navigation.active;

  $scope.changeActiveLink = function(link) {
    navigation.active.link = link;
  }
});
```

(*just remember to make necessary changes in your html code in that second case*)